# App working on Ginger Bread,but not working on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Ok, I tested my Live Wallpaper on a Samsung Galaxy Y and a Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos, but when i test it on a Xperia E and Xperia J, it says ,"Unfortunately the Live wallpaper has stopped unexpectedly". I tested it on the emulator with API Level 17. It worked fine.

```
        public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(); 
   }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

/*Method called when the Live Wallpaper loads on device.*/  
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    context = this;
    return new MyWallpaperEngine();

}

/*Creating a context to refer to the class.*/
Context context;
```

/*Definition of the WallpaperEngine class*/

```
        private class MyWallpaperEngine extends Engine implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

        /*Instance Variables of the above class.*/  
        private final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        private SharedPreferences   mPreferences;
        private String              mMode = "random";
        private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }
        };
        public Bitmap[] image = new Bitmap[26];
        private boolean visible;
        private int i ;


        public MyWallpaperEngine() {


        image[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image1);
        image[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image2);
        image[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image3);
        image[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image4);
        image[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image5);
        image[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image6);
        image[6] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image7);
        image[7] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image8);
        image[8] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image9);
        image[9] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image10);
        image[10] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image11);
        image[11] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image12);
        image[12] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image13);
        image[13] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image14);
        image[14] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image15);
        image[15] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image16);
        image[16] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image17);
        image[17] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image18);
        image[18] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image19);
        image[19] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image20);
        image[20] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image21);
        image[21] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image22);
        image[22] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image23);
        image[23] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image24);
        image[24] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.image25);

        mPreferences = LiveWallpaper.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        mPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPreferences,null); 
        handler.post(drawRunner);
    }

             public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        mMode = prefs.getString("livewallpaper_mode", "random");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
    {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        setTouchEventsEnabled(true);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        this.visible = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
    }

    private void draw() {
        Random random = new Random();// Creates a new random generator.
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();//Creates a surface controller
        Canvas canvas = null;//Sets the canvas to null
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                DisplayMetrics metrics =   context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;//Gets the metrics width
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;//Gets the metrics height
                    if(mMode.compareToIgnoreCase("aerial") == 0){

                         i = AERIAL_MIN + random.nextInt(AERIAL_MAX);
                         canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image[i],
                                 width, height, false), 0, 0, null);
                    }else if(mMode.compareToIgnoreCase("pitchside")==0){
                        i = AERIAL_MAX + random.nextInt(PITCH_MAX-AERIAL_MAX);
                         canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image[i],
                                 width, height, false), 0, 0, null);
                    }else if(mMode.compareToIgnoreCase("stadium")==0){
                        i = PITCH_MAX + random.nextInt(STAD_MAX-PITCH_MAX);
                         canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image[i],
                                 width, height, false), 0, 0, null);
                    }else {
                        i = random.nextInt(STAD_MAX);
                         canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image[i],
                                 width, height, false), 0, 0, null);
                    }       
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (visible) {
            handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 10000);//Called to delay(pause the thread)     the image by 10000 milliseconds
        }
       }
     }
   }
```

Logcat :

```
     07-06 21:50:28.807: W/dalvikvm(14567): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cfa498)
     07-06 21:50:28.907: W/BugSenseHandler(14567): Transmitting crash Exception Unable to resolve host "bugsense.appspot.com": No address associated with hostname
     07-06 21:50:31.857: E/test(14567): Exception
     07-06 21:50:31.857: E/test(14567): OutOfMemoryError
     07-06 21:50:32.487: E/dalvikvm(14567): can't open /mnt/sdcard/20130706-162031.hprof: Permission denied
     07-06 21:50:32.497: E/test(14567): writeHprofDataToFile: caught java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure during heap dump; check log output for details
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:376)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:406)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at app.sunny.soccerstadiumlivewallpaper.LiveWallpaper$MyWallpaperEngine.<init> (LiveWallpaper.java:118)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at app.sunny.soccerstadiumlivewallpaper.LiveWallpaper.onCreateEngine(LiveWallpaper.java:59)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1012)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
     07-06 21:50:32.507: E/AndroidRuntime(14567):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I didn't test it on the device by usb debugging. I installed the apk.

Comment: I suspect an `OutOfMemoryError` when setting those images in your code due to a higher dpi device screen.

Comment: So,how can it be solved ?

Comment: First, make sure that's indeed the error (by initializing only an image maybe or setting the same tiny new drawable to all of your images). Then you can reduce size or place resized drawables in their respective drawable-xxx folders, depending on the dpi of the installed phone.

Comment: Ok, I will do that & get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: And also check this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: @Voicu Posted the logcat after connecting the device to Eclipse. There seems to be a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.apperhand.device.android.AndroidSDKProvider error. Please help !

Comment: If you're using StartApp, make sure you're not skipping any steps in your integration. https://support.startapp.com/entries/22005202-Integrating-the-StartApp-SDK-to-your-App

Comment: Well, Start App works on other devices, then why not this one ?

Comment: It could be due to the vendor-specific permissions you have to set for this platform.

Comment: @Voicu Solved the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError by following other questions here on StackOverflow. Now,there's a java.lang.OutofMemory Error as YOU **suspected**. Following your previous advice and trying to fix the issue. Please have a look at the edited logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading 25 images into your Memory:
    image[24] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image25);
So why do you do that?

I think you'll never show all of them at the same time (you can't, the display is too small). So try reading the images *on demand* only.
And if you're willing to show some thumbs, then create some and put those small pictures into your drawable/res folder.

You should never have more than one image in your memory.

Also have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/best-performance.html